# Cassandra partition key for time series data

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm testing Cassandra as time series database.

I create data model as below:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE sm WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': 1
};

USE sm;

CREATE TABLE newdata (timestamp timestamp,
  deviceid int, tagid int,
  decvalue decimal,
  alphavalue text,
  PRIMARY KEY (deviceid,tagid,timestamp));
```

In the Primary key, I set deviceid as the partition key which mean all data with same device id will write into one node (does it mean one machine or one partition. Each partition can have max 2 billion rows) also if I query data within the same node, the retrieval will be fast, am I correct?  I’m new to Cassandra and a bit confused about the partition key and clustering key.

Most of my query will be as below:

- select lastest timestamp of know deviceid and tagid
- Select decvalue of known deviceid and tagid and timestamp
- Select alphavalue of known deviceid and tagid and timestamp
- select * of know deviceid and tagid with time range
- select * of known deviceid with time range

I will have around 2000 deviceid, each deviceid will have 60 tagid/value pair. I'm not sure if it will be a wide rows of deviceid, timestamp, tagid/value, tagid/value....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I’m new to Cassandra and a bit confused about the partition key and clustering key.

It sounds like you understand partition keys, so I'll just add that your partition key helps Cassandra figure out where (which token range) in the cluster to store your data.  Each node is responsible for several primary token ranges (assuming vnodes).  When your data is written to a data partition, it is sorted by your clustering keys.  This is also how it is stored on-disk, so remember that your clustering keys determine the order in which your data is stored on disk.

> Each partition can have max 2 billion rows

That's not exactly true.  Each partition can support up to 2 billion *cells*.  A cell is essentially a column name/value pair.  And your clustering keys add up to a single cell by themselves.  So compute your cells by counting the column values that you store for each CQL row, and add one more if you use clustering columns.

Depending on your wide row structure you will probably have a limitation of far fewer than 2 billion rows.  Additionally, that's just the storage limitation.  Even if you managed to store 1 million CQL rows in a single partition, querying that partition would return so much data that it would be ungainly and probably time-out.

> if I query data within the same node, the retrieval will be fast, am I correct?

It'll at least be faster than multi-key queries that hit multiple nodes.  But whether or not it will be "fast" depends on other things, like how wide your rows are, and how often you do things like deletes and in-place updates.

> Most of my query will be as below:
>
> ```
> select lastest timestamp of know deviceid and tagid
> Select decvalue of known deviceid and tagid and timestamp
> Select alphavalue of known deviceid and tagid and timestamp
> select * of know deviceid and tagid with time range
> select * of known deviceid with time range
> ```

Your current data model can support all of those queries, except for the last one.  In order to perform a range query on `timestamp`, you'll need to duplicate your data into a new table, and build a PRIMARY KEY to support that query pattern.  This is called "query-based modeling."  I would build a query table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newdata_by_deviceid_and_time (
  timestamp timestamp,
  deviceid int,
  tagid int,
  decvalue decimal,
  alphavalue text,
  PRIMARY KEY (deviceid,timestamp));
```

That table can support a range query on `timestamp`, while partitioning on `deviceid`.

But the biggest problem I see with either of these models, is that of "unbounded row growth."  Basically, as you collect more and more values for your devices, you will approach the 2 billion cell limit per partition (and again, things will probably get slow way before that).  What you need to do, is use a modeling technique called "time bucketing."

For the example, I'll say that I determined that bucketing by month would keep me well under the 2 billion cells limit *and* allow for the type of date range flexibility that I needed.  If so, I would add an additional partition key `monthbucket` and my (new) table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newdata_by_deviceid_and_time (
  timestamp timestamp,
  deviceid int,
  tagid int,
  decvalue decimal,
  alphavalue text,
  monthbucket text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((deviceid,monthbucket),timestamp));
```

Now when I wanted to query for data in a specific device and date range, I would also specify the `monthbucket`:

```
SELECT * FROM newdata_by_deviceid_and_time
WHERE deviceid='AA23' AND monthbucket='201603'
AND timestamp >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00-0500'
AND timestamp < '2016-03-16 00:00:00-0500';
```

Remember, `monthbucket` is just an example.  For you, it may make more sense to use quarter or even year (assuming that you don't store too many values per `deviceid` in a year).

Comment: Thanks you so much Aaron! that was really help...I'll do what you suggest I also try to trim some fat of my data model because some how cassandra consume CPU, RAM, IO and storage much higher than Mongo.

Comment: Hi Aaron, to optimise this data model, can I some how create the table using map {'tagid1':value1,'tagid2':value2}, Can I reduce hardware demand by doing this without suffering the performance?

Comment: @PhuongLe No, you won't gain any performance by storing all data in a map or concatenated string.

Comment: On the partition key, can I collate deviceid with a column that will auto increase when the cell count reach 1 billion or something? is there any cell count function or technique like this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I know this is years later but your answer had put more clarity into something I am trying to achieve that is similar. Could you have a moment to look into my table designs and offer some advice? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @realnsleo of course!  Feel free to ask a new question here on SO, or look for the link (in my bio) to our Discord server and ask there.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron for your response! I asked a question here and I have edited to provide more context. I look forward to your thoughts. Thank you again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010317/recommended-cassandra-schema-to-store-application-logs

Comment: In your answer @Aaron, can the query be - `SELECT * FROM newdata_by_deviceid_and_time
WHERE monthbucket='201603'
AND timestamp >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00-0500'
AND timestamp < '2016-03-16 00:00:00-0500';` i.e. not using deviceId in the where clause? I am trying to find a solution where I can get records between 2 timestamps only.

Comment: @dev_in_prog Good question!  Unfortunately, this query will not work without the `deviceid`. This is because it is a part of the partition key, and Cassandra needs both `deviceid` and `monthbucket` to hash-out a token for the driver to know which node(s) the data is stored on.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I guess I would use just use monthbucket and timestamp as clustering key in my case to be able to query for a time range in timestamp column  `PRIMARY KEY (monthbucket, timestamp)`;